# How to resolve this ReferenceError?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a web application based on Django. I use the [Scrapy Crawler](http://scrapy.org/) to crawl webpages. My goal, at the moment, is to be able to control the crawler from within a webpage using jQuery and AJAX requests.

My theoretical setup is the following:

- On the webpage, I have a button. When I click the button, the crawler is started on the server-side.
- Once the crawler has started, I periodically send AJAX GET requests to the server using [`window.setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval) to find out how many webpages have been crawled so far.
- Once the crawler has finished, the GET requests should stop by using [`window.clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.clearInterval).

These are the relevant lines from my current code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // This variable will hold the ID returned by setInterval
    var monitorCrawlerId;

    $startCrawlerButton.on('click', function(event) {

        // This function should be run periodically using setInterval
        var monitorCrawler = function() {

            $.ajax({

                type: 'GET',
                url: '/monitor_crawler/',
                // ...
                success: function(response) {

                    // if the server sends the message that the crawler
                    // has stopped, use clearInterval to stop executing this function
                    if (response.crawler_status == 'finished') {

                        clearInterval(monitorCrawlerId);

                    }

                } 

            });

        };

        // Here I send an AJAX POST request to the server to start the crawler
        $.ajax({

            type: 'POST',
            url: '/start_crawler/',
            // ...
            success: function(response) {

                // If the form that the button belongs to validates correctly,
                // call setInterval with the function monitorCrawler defined above
                if (response.validation_status == 'success') {

                    monitorCrawlerId = setInterval('monitorCrawler()', 10000);

                }

            }

        });

    });
});
```

**The problem:** When I execute this code, I get this in Firefox's web console:

```
ReferenceError: monitorCrawler is not defined
```

The strange thing, however, is that the function `monitorCrawler` gets periodically executed anyway. But with every execution, I get the same error message again. If I put `monitorCrawler` outside of `$startCrawlerButton.on()` I still get the same errors. How can I resolve this? Since I'm a JavaScript newbie, any help is appreciated. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setInterval`, when first parameter is string, resolves in the global (`window`) context. You can give it a variable pointing to the function to be called or even:

```
setInterval(function(){monitorCrawler();}, 10000);
```

this will create a closure where local variable `monitorCrawler` will still exist when interval fires.

Comment: Thanks, Igor. :) This is exactly what I need. In this way, I can add parameters to `monitorCrawler()` which is necessary in my case. Since you were the first one posting this particular solution, I accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
setInterval('monitorCrawler()', 10000);
```

to

```
setInterval(monitorCrawler, 10000);
```

Never ever pass strings to [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval), but function references! They will be `eval`ed every time, and that in global scope - yet your `monitorCrawler` function is local to the click-handler (and I guess by "putting it outside" you meant "into the ready-callback").

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
monitorCrawlerId = setInterval(monitorCrawler, 10000);
```

With parameters:

```
monitorCrawlerId = setInterval(function(){
      //prepare params.
      monitorCrawler(/* param1, param2*/);
   }, 10000);
```

Comment: Okay, this works but in this way I cannot pass any parameters to `monitorCrawler`, right? I actually need to do that in my code but left that out in my question to keep it simple.

Comment: see my answer with anonymous function as first parameter

Comment: Right, you can create anonymous function as @Igor said.

Comment: Cool, the version from @Igor works exactly the way I need it. I take his answer as the accepted one because he posted it earlier than you, Yury. Anyway, thanks a lot. :)

Comment: @PeterStahl: you are welcome. Just remember never ever pass code to setInterval again as Bergi pointed out. :)